# AD Script - Account Management

Tags: shell, active-directory

I wrote this at my old company, as there was a lot of account lockouts/expired/or just needing to check on accounts, it was faster for me to run this in powershell, and just typing things out then to go to Active Directory. I tried to modify it for my current company, but am now getting an error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the
argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:3 char:12
```

---

I wrote it long ago, and now i can't exactly remember what I need to do to fix it, and was hoping someone here could help.

This is what I have:

```
function pcpwd {
Get-AdmPwdPassword
}

function iinfo {
$kpmguser = Read-Host 'Enter User Name'
Get-ADUser $flightsafetyuser -Properties Displayname, LockedOut, badPwdCount, AccountLockoutTime, PasswordExpired, AccountExpirationDate, Enabled | Select-Object -Property Name, Displayname, badPwdCount, AccountLockoutTime,AccountExpirationDate,Enabled,PasswordExpired,LockedOut
}

function iUnlockAD {
$flightsafetyuser = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter User Name'
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $kpmguser -verbose
}

function ipwdreset{
$flightsafetyuser = read-host -Prompt 'Enter User Name'
Set-ADAccountPassword $flightsafetyuser -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText “Flight1!” -Force -Verbose) -Reset -PassThru | Set-ADuser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -Verbose; Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $flightsafetyuser -verbose
}
```

Comment: Best if you include an example "call" to these functions to show what sort of arguments you are passing in. In the future, pls use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you everything you need to know:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

If you look at the `Identity` parameter in the [`Get-ADUser` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser), it shows:

> Position: 0

That means it is a [position argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#position-argument), which means that you don't need to include the name of the parameter as long as it is at position 0 (the first parameter).

The first parameter in your call to `Get-ADUser` is `$flightsafetyuser`, which means that corresponds to the `-Identity` parameter.

In short, `$flightsafetyuser` is null and that's what you need to fix.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something silly. I changed it to fsiuser, and now all is working. Thanks again!